# How to reveal empty cells in a minesweeper game?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been working on programming a minesweeper game using javascript/jquery. I can't seem to get the empty cell revealed. My algorithm was to reveal 8 adjacents of the clicked empty cell. When i click on the div, I get clicked 8 times in console and it messes up the adjElements values. Any help how to make it work?

Here what i've done so far.

```
//my divs are generated with a function from id '#s-1' to '#s-81'
var adj=[-10,-9,-8,-1,1,8,9,10];

$('.grid').find('div').click(function(event) {

        var div=this.id;
        var numDiv=div.replace( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
        revealSquare(numDiv);
    });


var revealSquare=function(square) {

     if(!($(square).hasClass('isMine'))) {

            if($(square).find('span').text()=='') {

                revealEmptyCells(square);

                     }  
            }


};


var revealEmptyCells=function(clickDiv) {

    $.each(adj, function(index, val) {

        if(val+clickDiv>0 && val+clickDiv<=81) {

                    var adjElements=val+clickDiv;
                    console.log('adj: '+adjElements); //it reveals odd numbers like for div #s-1 it reveals 19
                    $('#s-'+adjElements).css({
                            border: '4px solid #d4d4d3',
                         });
}

    }); 
}
```

Assuming that the clicked div is empty, and I removed the val+clickDiv>0 and val+clickDiv<=81; If I click on div s-1, the adj elements are -101,-91,-81,-11,11,81,91,101. Why do I get these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform the `+` operation, and one of the operands is a string, then the result will not be the mathematical sum, but the concatenation of the two:

In your case the following is not a number, but a string:

```
div.replace( /[^\d.]/g, '' )
```

To solve this, just add the unitary `+` before it:

```
+div.replace( /[^\d.]/g, '' )
```

Now *numDiv* will be a number and will have the desired effect in an addition.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Can you explain why it worked? and what went wrong? I'm new at javascript.

Comment: I think I explained that in my answer? Your code was rendering 1 + 9 as 19, while it should render it 10. The operands must be numeric to make it work.